# What is the Versus symbol?

Tags: notation

I've never really studied math, but was wondering, is there a designated symbol used for implying "versus", or would you just write "Vs."?

For example, I'm working on a calculation like this:

```
Cost expense A "versus" cost expense B
+ cost expense C
+ cost expense D
- Expense E
= Total 1 vs Total 2
```

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco edited the question a bit. hopefully it's clearer now.

Comment: Nope, no clue whatever what you mean. What _mathematical_ concept are you using the word "versus" for?

Comment: @larry909 : Do you mean the *difference* between expense A and expense B? More information, please!

Comment: @zahbaz seems to understand and answered satisfactorily . But it's not inherently a mathamaticaly correct question because it's​ a theoretical mathematical concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no commonly used symbol for versus of which I'm aware. What you're asking for seems closest to some usage of the exclusive OR symbol (i.e XOR, $\oplus$), but I don't think that works here, as you seem to be looking for one number or the other, not a logical output.

You could use a vector equation to have both numbers present

\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix} A \\ B \end{pmatrix} + C + D - E = \begin{pmatrix} T_A \\ T_B \end{pmatrix} 
\end{align}

where it is implied that $C,D,E$ are multiplied by $\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$ and where $T_A,T_B$ represent the totals in either scenario.